# PrimeFaces template navigation using <p:MenuItem>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation, menuitem

I've read several threads on stackoverflow regarding this problem but I've not found a solution yet.

In my index.xhtml template I define a navigation and a content layoutUnit.
the menu is a basic `<p:menu>` menu.

Filling the content panel with another site, e.g. page1.xhtml by using `<p:commandButton>` works well.
Navigation with `<p:menuItem>` doesn't work. I've tried setting `ajax="false"`, changed `action` to `actionListener`. nothing helps. where is the secret? :)

**index.xhtml:**

```
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50" id="top">
            <h:form>
                <ui:include src="/template/header.xhtml" />
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="50">
            <h:form>
                <ui:include src="/template/footer.xhtml" />
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="350" >
            <h:form>
                <ui:include src="/template/mainmenu.xhtml" />
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" >
            <h:panelGroup id="contentPanel">
                <ui:include src="#{navController.pageName}.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

**mainmenu.xhtml:**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formMainMenu">      

            <p:menu>            
                <p:submenu label="Menu">
                    <p:menuitem value="Link I" action="#{navController.navigateTo}" ajax="false" update=":contentPanel" icon="ui-icon-disk">
                        <f:param name="navParam" value="/pages/page1" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menu>
```

THIS WORKS:

```
            <p:commandButton value="Link I" action="#{navController.navigateTo}" update=":contentPanel">
                <f:param name="navParam" value="/pages/page1" />
            </p:commandButton>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**navController navigation method:**

```
public void navigateTo() 
{
     String target = acesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("navParam");
     setPageName(target);
}
```

Comment: hmm.. it seems that even a basic actionListener like `<p:menuitem value="Display Message" actionListener="#{navController.message}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-disk" />` is not called. i'm in debug mode and it never jumps into message method :/ when i put this into a <p:commandButton> it just works..

Comment: actionListener on menuItem works for basic `actionListener="#{navController.message}"` when running mainmenu.xhtml directly - not from index.xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

([Question edit converted to an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

The OP wrote:

> hmm.. it seems that even a basic `actionListener` like
>
> ```
> <p:menuitem value="Display Message" actionListener="#{navController.message}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
> ```
>
> is not called. I'm in debug mode and it never jumps into message method :/ when I put this into a `<p:commandButton>` it just works..
>
> `actionListener` on `menuItem` works for basic `actionListener="#{navController.message}"` when running `mainmenu.xhtml` directly - not from `index.xhtml`.
>
> I finally solved the problem by removing the `<h:form id="formMainMenu"> </h:form>` tags from my `mainmenu.xhtml`.
>
> An explanation why this worked for the `commandButton` but not for `menuItem` would be great! thanks!